# Upgraded from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and no video output on startup

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, xubuntu, display

I waited for the 20.04.1 release of ubuntu for upgrading my system from Xubuntu 18.04 and it finally became available. I upgraded using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt --purge autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The upgrade indicated no errors other than something about VirtualBox (can't remember exactly what now, but VirtualBox did seem to work). After rebooting, the display remained blank - no startup indicaton at all. From few searches on this error, I tried the suggestion to do ctrl-Alt-F2 to get a terminal in which I was able to login and run the command startx to start the GUI. I believe the author of that was indicating it was due to running the xfce interface of ubuntu instead of the default gnome, so the xfce drivers weren't getting loaded. Everything seemed to work fine after that, but I changed wallpaper settings and power settings (disabling sleep, hibernation, shutting display off after timeout). I worked all day with the system and when I rebooted, I got the blank screen again. This time, however, ctrl-Alt-F2 does not give me a terminal.

My system is an Intel NUC 6i5 with 16 GB RAM and 250 GB SSD drive (71% full following the upgrade). I have a ViewSonic 32" monitor connected to it, but I also tried a 22" LG monitor as well. Not sure what the problem is since I have no display, but it is connected to an external hard drive, which I can hear spin up when it comes on. Other than that and the power LED igniting, I have no other signs of life.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F2. It will then ask you for your username. Type in your username. It will then ask you for your password. Type in your password. You are using a virtual terminal when you press Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Same thing happens with Ctrl+Alt+F2-6. Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings you back to the GUI.

Try running  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the virtual terminal. Then select the option that you aren't using. After that, do `sudo shutdown now -r`. That will restart your PC. It should work now. If it still doesn't work, follow the steps in the 1st paragraph, then go to the 4th paragraph.

After you reboot and are in the virtual terminal again, type `sudo lightdm` or `sudo`  followed by the other option from the sudo dpkg-reconfigure command, then follow the step in the 2nd paragraph. The login screen should be there now. You might have to do this without seeing the screen.